# How to check if the head branch match a specific pattern on branch pull request in Github actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, pipeline, github-actions

I would like the write something like this inside my Github workflow action:

```
name: Deploy to branch with a specific pattern

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: master && contains(github.ref, 'myPattern') # The current head branch contains a specific word
```

However, it didn't work and I don't want to use `if` after running the job to stop it like following

```
name: Deploy to branch with a specific pattern

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: master

jobs:
  deployment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: contains(github.ref, 'myPattern')
```

So any Idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation has this pretty clearly. https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths

> When using the push and pull_request events, you can configure a workflow to run on specific branches or tags. For a pull_request event, only branches and tags on the base are evaluated. If you define only tags or only branches, the workflow won't run for events affecting the undefined Git ref.
>
> The branches, branches-ignore, tags, and tags-ignore keywords accept glob patterns that use the * and ** wildcard characters to match more than one branch or tag name. For more information, see the "[Filter pattern cheat sheet](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet)."

```
on:
  push:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/heads
    branches:    
      - master         # Push events on master branch
      - 'mona/octocat' # Push events to branches matching refs/heads/mona/octocat
      - 'releases/**'  # Push events to branches matching refs/heads/releases/10
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/tags
    tags:        
      - v1             # Push events to v1 tag
      - v1.*           # Push events to v1.0, v1.1, and v1.9 tags
```

```
Filter pattern cheat sheet
You can use special characters in path, branch, and tag filters.

*: Matches zero or more characters, but does not match the / character. For example, Octo* matches Octocat.
**: Matches zero or more of any character.
?: Matches zero or one single character. For example, Octoc?t matches Octocat.
+: Matches one or more of the proceeding character.
[] Matches one character listed in the brackets or included in ranges. Ranges can only include a-z, A-Z, and 0-9. For example, the range[0-9a-f] matches any digits or lowercase letter. For example, [CB]at matches Cat or Bat and [1-2]00 matches 100 and 200.
!: At the start of a pattern makes it negate previous positive patterns. It has no special meaning if not the first character.
```

Comment: poster said head branch